# fade background images with css3

Tags: css, transition

Hey everyone...
Im wondering why this wont work?

```
.right-article.boy {
    background: transparent url(../images/boxes-bg/boy.jpg) left top no-repeat;
    width: 413px;
    height: 242px;
    -webkit-transition: background 1.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: background 1.5s linear;
    transition: background 1.5s linear;
}

.right-article.boy:hover {
    background: transparent url(../images/boxes-bg/boy-hover.jpg) left top no-repeat;
}
```

If i change the background to colors like yellow and the hover, black, it works fine.... But not with my images?

Answer (score 3):

i can't imagine how image would change during 1.5s.
i would do this a little bit different:
 http://jsfiddle.net/seler/48BM4/1/ or http://jsfiddle.net/seler/48BM4/2/

with images it would work like that:
http://jsfiddle.net/seler/48BM4/3/

another example iwth auto height and no need to duplicate content:
http://jsfiddle.net/seler/48BM4/7/

Comment: That's exactly what the OP mentioned above. It works with a background colour but not an image.

Comment: @anothershrubery fact that in first example i haven't used image doesnt mean that it wont work with images. see third example

Comment: Third example using images doesn't work, which is what the OP asks for. Also, you should post relevant code that answers the question in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/ – I wrote this tutorial to help people with issues like this!

Comment: That's right, it's not a competition, but thought that the range of information would help. I voted you up before posting by the way.