# How to fade-in and fade-out background-image with CSS transition?

Tags: css, dojo

I have an element which does not have a background image when the app is loaded. Then when a button is clicked, a CSS class gets added to the element which sets the background-image for that element for a few seconds. Problem is - I can't get the background image to fade-in and fade-out.

What I tried:

```
.MyBox.formElementInput {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 65px center;
background-size: "contain";
-webkit-transition:background-image 2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: background-image 2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: background-image 2s ease-in-out;
transition: background-image 2s ease-in-out;
}

.MyBox.formElementInput.showSpinner {
    background-image : url("/PmDojo/dojox/widget/Standby/images/loading.gif");
}
```

EDIT: JQuery is not an option.

Comment: What do you mean? Right now it "slides" into position rather than "fades" in.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947582/fade-background-images-with-css3

Comment: @PatrickJamesMcDougle yeah no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS doesn't fade or animate background images without a javascript plugin. If you want an only CSS option, you need to wrap it in a div, and fade in/out the whole div.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the content of the `div` fading in/out as well:

```
#div-with-bg{                
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.5s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1.5s linear;
    transition: opacity 1.5s linear;
    background: url(background.png);
    opacity: 0;
}
#div-with-bg:hover{
    opacity: 1;
}
```