# CSS3(Or jQuery)Fade in Image

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

So, I have a little bit of code, and what I want to modify it to do, is have a specific background image, then fade in a different one on hover.
I was just wondering, CSS3 or jQuery.
If you want to suggest one, a good place on how to achieve this would be nice too.

Comment: Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319552/can-i-fade-in-a-background-image-css-background-image-with-jquery or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947582/fade-background-images-with-css3 ?

Comment: The first one didn't work for me, the second doesn't use background images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/GaYKF/56/

Use jquery:

```
 $("#myDiv").hover(
function(){
  $(this).fadeTo('slow', 0.3, function()
    {
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url("http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-tOHKWImzMJQ/TlHqjy1C_II/AAAAAAAAAWw/T5WGegi1sVc/s320/blue+%25288%2529.jpg")');
    }).fadeTo('slow', 1);
}, 
function(){
   $(this).fadeTo('slow', 0.3, function()
    {
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url("http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-nI97Eqlkfh0/TlHp2CS0_XI/AAAAAAAAAWU/kRGbOd6YNZg/s320/blue+%25281%2529.jpg")');
    }).fadeTo('slow', 1);
});
```

Comment: Didn't quite work...it set the background image to the second image, and than didn't work..

Comment: You changed it, just a sec

Comment: Okay, just give me till tomorrow to test, kinda busy currently.

Answer (score 0):

To complete Mennan's solution, if you use jQuery, do it like this to change the background image on hover on a element (`<div>` in this case).

```
$('#mydiv').mouseenter( function() {
  $(this).css('background-image','url(/images/second.png)');
}).mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).css('background-image','url(/images/original.png)');
});
```